# Shortest logic to calculate hours from overlapped time php

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate no of hours of user. If many schedules assigned to him.

Schedules are -

```
10:00 AM - 12 pm
11 am - 12 pm
9 am - 12 pm
8 am - 5 pm
```

These schedules are assigned to a user.
I have to calculate no of hours how much time he is spending on these schedules.

Is there any shortest method to calculate this ?

I want answer = 8 hours. I dnt want to calculate the diff I want no of hours.

NO I want the result 8.. I explain why
10:00 AM - 12 pm --- 2 hour,
11 am - 12 pm ---- 1 hour already added ,
9 am - 12 pm ----- 3 hour but    10 - 12  already added so 1 hour,
8 am - 5 pm ---- 8 hours

Comment: Convert times to 24h format and compute the difference.

Comment: so you want to compute for that total, using that whole string? `$time = '10:00 AM - 12 pm
11 am - 12 pm
9 am - 12 pm
8 am - 5 pm';`?

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be 9 hours? 8 - 5 being the longest timespan

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$minutes_diff = round(abs(strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2)) / 60);
```

Or this:

```
$time1="7.30 AM";
$time2="8.30 PM";

$d1=  strtotime($time1);
$d2=  strtotime($time2);

$diff=$d2-$d1;

//Print the difference in hours : minutes
echo date("H:i",$diff);
```

Comment: I want answer = 8 hours. I dnt want to calculate the diff I want no of hours.

Comment: @NidhiSen the diff IS the number of hours the user spend on it?

Comment: @NidhiSen and how did you came up with 8?

Comment: @Ghost he added all the diffs together.

Comment: @Ghost no wait even that isn't 8

Comment: @StijnBernards yes, where did the OP got the figure, its way over 8

Comment: @StijnBernards the differences each line are 2, 1, 3, 9

Comment: NO I want the result 8.. I explain why                             10:00 AM - 12 pm --- 2 hour
11 am - 12 pm ---- 1 hour already added
9 am - 12 pm ----- 3 hour but    10 - 12  already added so 1 hour
8 am - 5 pm ---- 8 hours

Comment: @NidhiSen shouldn't your correct answer be 9 hours.

Comment: I am trying by this but sometimes it is giving wrong answer can you please help in correcting this                                          $shifts = "10:00 12:00 | 21:00 23:45 | 08:00 12:45 | 09:00 05:00 | 20:00 21:45 ";
$shifts= explode('|', $shifts);

$sum = 0;    

foreach($shifts as $shift) {
    $times = explode(' ', trim($shift));
    $start = explode(':', $times[0]);
    $end = explode(':', $times[1]);

    $sum += ($end[0] - $start[0]) + ($end[1] - $start[1]) / 100 / 0.6;
}

echo $sum; // prints the result 27

Comment: Any Update about this problem??

Comment: @NidhiSen you should make a function to get the highest time 5 pm and the lowest 8 am

Comment: These times are not fixed time may be different.

Comment: @NidhiSen you should make a function to get the highest time 5 pm and the lowest 8 am

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script to sum the total amount of hours in a work schedule from start of the work day until the end:

```
// $key['date'] contains a date format of 'yyyy-mm-dd'
// $key['start'] and $key['end'] contains a time of format hh:mm:ss             
$start = new DateTime( $key['date'] .'T' . $key['start'] );
$end = new DateTime( $key['date'] .'T' . $key['end'] );

// difference returns the differential between start and end resulting in number of hours worked
$difference = $start->diff( $end );

// Additionally, I would like 1 hour and 15 minutes to result in 1.25 instead of 1.15 and so on. For this I used this:
$minute = $difference->format( '%i' )*1.666666666667;
$total = $difference->format( '%h' ) . '.' . $minute;
```

Comment: I am not getting this please elaborate

Comment: You could simplify it like this:
$start = new DateTime( '2014-09-17T10:00:00' );
$end = new DateTime( '2014-09-17T14:00:00' );
$difference = $start->diff( $end );
$total = $difference->format('%h');
echo $total //this will now result in '4' as is the total amount of hours between 10AM and 2PM