# calculate hours from overlapped time

Tags: php

I have various time ranges as like

```
10:00 12:00,
21:00 24:00,
11:30 12:00,
08:00 17:00
```

These are schedules of a user. I want to calculate total number of hours from These ranges but I dnt want to calculate repeated time. If i calculated any hour once then i dnt want to calculate that again. What should i do for this.

I am calculating hours by this. but how could i escape repeated time. which I have already counted.

```
$shifts = "10:00 12:00 | 21:00 24:00| 11:30 12:00|08:00 17:00";
$shifts = explode('|', $shifts);

$sum = 0;

$starts = array();
$ends = array();

foreach($shifts as $shift) {
    $times = explode(' ', trim($shift));
    $start = explode(':', $times[0]);
    $end = explode(':', $times[1]);

    $startime   = $start[0]*60 + $start[1];
    $endtime    = $end[0]*60 + $end[1];
    $flag = false;
    foreach ($starts as $key=>$start) {       
        if($startime < $start && $endtime > $ends[$key]) {
            $diff_old = ($start > $ends[$key]) ? $start - $ends[$key] : $ends[$key] - $start;
            $sum = $sum - $diff_old/60;
        }
        else if($startime > $start && $endtime <= $ends[$key]) {
            $flag = true;
            continue;
        }
    }   
    if($flag)
        continue;
    $starts[] = $startime;
    $ends[] = $endtime;  
    $diff = $startime > $endtime ? $startime - $endtime : $endtime - $startime;   
    $sum = $sum + $diff/60;
}

echo $sum;
```

I am trying this by above code but it is displaying wrong answer. because I dnt want to calculate hours which are already calculated. this time this is showing answer is 12 but correct answer is 10.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest logic to calculate hours from overlapped time php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846678/shortest-logic-to-calculate-hours-from-overlapped-time-php)

Comment: the OP's problem did not get a solution earlier, so its no point referencing it. I think.

Comment: I have posted this earlier also but I did not found any solution uptil yet. So I am looking for good answer. Please provide any help

Comment: That's not how it works here, you shouldn't post the question again just because you didn't get an answer the first time.

Comment: Okay if I didn't get the answer then what i do ?? go for any other way other than stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets consider the following. If we have two intervals `[8, 10]` and `[9, 12]` then the length of the union of the intervals is equal to the length of `[8, 12]`.

If we have two disjoint intervals (`[8, 9]` and `[10, 11]`) we don't need to do this merge of intervals to calculate the length. Instead we can just take the sum of the lengths of the intervals.

It is therefore logical to try to reduce the set of intervals to a set of disjoint intervals. Then the problem becomes trivial.

```
//Check if [a0, a1] and [b0, b1] are disjoint
function isDisjoint($a, $b) {
   if(in_array($a[0], $b) || in_array($a[1], $b)) {
      return false;
   }
   return ($a[0] < $b[0]) ? ($a[1] < $b[0]) : ($a[0] > $b[1]);
}

//Make sure $a and $b are not disjoint before calling.
function mergeIntervals($a, $b) {
   return array(min($a[0], $b[0]), max($a[1], $b[1]));
}

//Generate a set of disjoint intervals
function genetrateDisjointSet($set) {
   $output = array();
   while(!empty($set)) {
      $interval = array_pop($set);
      $intervalDisjoint = false;

      while(!$intervalDisjoint) {
        $intervalDisjoint = true;
        foreach($set as $key => $value) {
           if(!isDisjoint($interval, $value)) {
              $interval = mergeIntervals($interval, $value);
              unset($set[$key]);
              $intervalDisjoint = false;
           }
        }
     }

     array_push($output, $interval);
  }

  return $output;
}

//Calculate the length of the set of intervals
function calcLength($set) {
   $set = genetrateDisjointSet($set);
   $length = 0;

   foreach($set as $value) {
      $length += $value[1] - $value[0];
   }

   return $length;
}
```

We try this with your example

```
//You have to convert the time to minutes after 00:00.
$set = array(
   array(600, 720),
   array(1260, 1440),
   array(690, 720),
   array(480, 1020)
);
echo calcLength($set); //720 min = 12 h * 60
```

**Note** that `08:00` to `17:00` + `21:00` to `24:00` is `9 + 3 = 12`

**Edit** Changed the time to minutes after `00:00` instead of hours. Thanks to Dharman for the idea.

Comment: Instead of converting hours of the day into floating point numbers op could convert them to the minutes of the day. The final output then would have to be converted to hours again if desired.